# Why is my code outputting only "opened" and not "closed"?

Tags: javascript, rosetta-code

This is a 100 doors Rosseta code challenge. I have been trying to figure out why the output is all "opened". I don't understand why, since when I go through the loop, it makes sense logically.

```
function getFinalOpenedDoors(numDoors) {
  // Good luck!
  const DOOR_ARR = [];
  const FINALDOOR_ARR = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= numDoors; i++){
    DOOR_ARR.push("D" + i);
    //DOOR_ARR[i - 1] = "D" + i + " is closed";
    DOOR_ARR[i - 1] = "closed";
  }

  for(let j = 1; j <= numDoors; j ++){

    for(let n = 1; n <= numDoors / j; n ++){

      if(DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] = "closed"){

        DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] = "opened";


      }
      else{
        DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] = "closed";
      }
    }


        /*DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] = "D" + DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] + " is closed" ? "D" + DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] + " is opened" : "D" + DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] + " is closed";*/
  }

  return DOOR_ARR;
}
```

Comment: `if( something = "closed")` -- that's an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: You are missing a double `==` on `if(DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] = "closed"){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use `==` in your if statement:

```
if(DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] == "closed"){
```

Sorry I don't have the reputation to add a comment.

Comment: oh my! i totally missed that one. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

In the `if` statement you use the assignment operator `=` instead of comparison `===`.

```
      if(DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] = "closed"){
```

Should be

```
      if(DOOR_ARR[(n * j) - 1] === "closed"){
```